# SDL Software Rendering VS. OpenGL: Compatability And Performance

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl, sdl

I'm creating a simple computer games framework using SDL, and am still deciding between using SDL's software renderer (Which is also much easier to use than OpenGL), or the supposedly faster OpenGL, despite the fact that in Visual Studio 2008 I'm having troubles linking the OpenGL libraries. Any suggestions for which graphical interface to choose?

Comment: Stack Overflow is generally not the place for offering "suggestions". We prefer questions that have a single, definitive answer. Your question is more of a discussion or poll of "what do you think I should use?"

Comment: I see a potential question in there or questions rather.

Comment: Some more information about your link problem would be good.  Then with respect to the other question, well, many things are easier than OpenGL, but you learn to use OpenGL if you think you'll need to use it and we can't decide that because you don't specify the use-case apart from to say "simple computer games framework".

Comment: I'll only be rendering 2d graphics, and either way I'll load all of my textures using SDL. The average frame rate of my game will be 30 frames per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is .. depends.

You should ask yourself :

1. What is the number of polygons you will render per frame ?
2. What is the rendering rate (number of frames per second) that you wish to get ?
3. Do you expect the number of polygons to render increase in future ?

About Visual studio and linking problems, please find a sample project here that uses OpenGL. [OpenGL Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17326/2D-Drawing-with-an-OpenGL-Control).